# Azure App Service Hosting asp.NET core MVC App

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to get our existing asp.NET core mvc app to run in an azure app service. Deployment works fine and all files i would expect are on the server.

Sadly, after trying to visit the url I am greeted by the message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." which is the Statuscode 403.

The Log gives some more insight:

```
<div id="content"><div class="content-container"><h3>HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden</h3><h4>The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.</h4></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4><ul>     <li>A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.</li> </ul></fieldset></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4><ul>   <li>If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.</li>    <li>           Enable directory browsing using IIS Manager.           <ol>          <li>Open IIS Manager.</li>          <li>In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.</li>             <li>On the Directory Browsing page, in the Actions pane, click Enable.</li>         </ol>   </li>   <li>Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.</li>
```

It seems like I am supposed to use some sort of landing page like index.html but that is not present for the given mvc Project.

I couldn't find any documentation for this configuration either. Even the youtube videos showcasing how easy it is to host a mvc app don't have to do any further configuration. (for example this one: [watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTiMDaiDsXM))

I would be happy if anyone could tell me where I went wrong.

Thanks in advance,

Joshua

Comment: Have you tried changing items at "Configuration, Default documents" to a scenario that fits to you?

Comment: Well, since it is a mvc app there is no "Default document". The wwwroot folder contains both a .dll file of my application and a .exe file of my application. No static html files exist for this mvc project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deployed a .NET Core MVC application over Azure App Service via Visual Studio and it worked. So, I notice that on this process, VS creates a *web.config* file. Once I remove it from App Service via Kudu, the application stopped.

So, the solution is to create a *web.config* file in the *wwwroot* folder on App Service environment. The content is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\My.Main.Project.dll" 
stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" 
hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

For the record, the application was created on .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: That actually was the main issue. Thanks a lot!